# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the Service in Global Module

Tags: typescript, firebase, nestjs, nestjs-config, nestjs-passport

I have a global module called `FirebaseModule` which exports a `FirebaseService`, I import this module to the `app.module.ts` and then I try to use the `FirebaseService` inside a `UsersService` and it fails with a missing dependency issue.

Something interesting is that if I remove the usage on the service and use it only on the controller nothings fails but if I want to use it in the service provider, it starts failing.

My code:

`app.module.ts`

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    CustomLoggerModule,
    ConfigurationModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useExisting: ConfigurationService,
    }),
    FirebaseModule,
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`firebase.module.ts`

```
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [FirebaseService],
  exports: [FirebaseService],
})
export class FirebaseModule {}
```

`users.module.ts`

```
@Module({
  imports: [CqrsModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UsersRepository])],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService, ...CommandHandlers, ...EventHandlers],
  exports: [UsersService, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UsersRepository])],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

`users.controller.ts`

```
@Controller('users')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('firebase'))
export class UsersController {
  constructor(
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
    private readonly firebaseService: FirebaseService,
  ) {}
}
```

`users.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    private readonly firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    private readonly repository: UsersRepository,
  ) {}
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?, UsersRepository). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the UsersModule context.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular file reference in your UserService to the FirebaseService most likely. If Nest is able to resolve the name of the class/provider/injection token, it will say what that token is explicitly, but when it is unable to, all the comes out is `dependency`. [Here's a little more information from the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors)

Comment: There's no circular reference. If there where so, Nest tells you when you have a circular dependency.

Comment: I didn't say it was a circular reference (i.e. classA depends on classB depends on classA) I said it was a circular file import (fileA imports fileB imports fileA) and this chain can be rather well nested, but it is a circular file import. If you can provide access to your code, I can find it.

Comment: I moved the firebase module to its own folder and it fixed it! Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing it was a barrel file import?

Comment: Yes, I think it had to do with that I was exporting the whole folder in an index file and in another file I was using that service.