# NestJS - Inject factory provider into another provider doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I'm trying to use nest custom provider with factory, for some reason I'm struggling to get it working.
I've created the following sample -

```
interface ProviderOptions: {x:string, y:number};
interface AsyncProps {useFactory:(...args:any[])=> ProviderOptions, inject:any[], imports:any[] }

@Module({})
export class MyModule {
    
   static forRootAsync(asyncProps: AsyncProps): DynamicModule {
        
     const myFactory: Provider = {
          provide: "MY_PROVIDER",
          useFactory: asyncProps.useFactory,
          inject: asyncProps.inject,
        };
    
     return {
        module: MyModule,
        providers: [myFactory, MyService],
        exports: [MyService],
        imports: [...asyncProps.imports],
        };
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

   constructor(@Inject("MY_PROVIDER") this options:ProviderOptions){

   }
}
```

For some reason I'm unable to resolve MyService -

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MyService (?). Please
> make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in
> the MyModule context.

what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

UPDATE -
so now it's really strange -
originally MyService was in a different file, next to MyModule. when moved MyService to the same file as MyModule, the above code does work as expected. how can it be?

Comment: How are you using the `MyService` in the consuming module?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I'm injecting it via the constructor. however even without consuming it at all - Nest failed to load since he cant resolve the MyService dependency.

Comment: But what does the consuming code of this look like? What's the full error? There's isn't enough here to know what's wrong

Comment: @JayMcDoniel updated inline. Also now this code works when moving the class to the same file as the module. Do you have any explanation for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your error, you have a circular file import which means that typecript can't resolve the class name and in turn Nest can't create the class. I [just answered another question on it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67219950/nest-cant-resolve-dependencies-of-the-service-in-global-module)

Comment: Thanks! it does looks like it. "MY_PROVIDER" was a const in the module file, so the service file had a reference to that file. moving the token to const file solved the issue.